# Upload of app package (Windows Application Packaging Project) to Azure App Service possible?

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-web-app-service, packaging

I published my app Windows Application Packaging project as an app package.

The app installer and index.html are successfully published to the specified folder on my system. I can open the index.html and the app installer works.

If I upload the folder to my Azure App Service through FTP, the standard page doesn't get replaced by index.html.

I'm new to Azure and never worked with the Windows Application Packaging project before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please refer this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-website-to-azure-using-ftp/ may it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> If I upload the folder to my Azure App Service through FTP, the
> standard page doesn't get replaced by index.html.

It worked for me when I tried to download and upload my `index.html` file to Azure using [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) client.

1. Created an Azure app service
2. Copy host name, user name and password of FTP(as shown in below image)
3. Install **WinScp** .
4. Enter credential that we copied earlier and login.
5. Delete the current html file from the www root.(as shown in below image)
6. Go to your local file location and drag and drop the `index.html` file which you want for your project.

Here are the screenshots for your reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Output of my designed `index.html` after replacing**  :

[image]

NOTE:

> In same way we can use other client apps like
> [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) as mentioned in the given document below.

Please refer the Microsoft Azure tutorial: [How to upload a website to the cloud via FTP](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/student-developer-blog/microsoft-azure-tutorial-how-to-upload-a-website-to-the-cloud/ba-p/311793) & this is for [Deploy files to azure| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal#deploy-files-to-azure)  .

Comment: If the provided answer helped you, Could you please accept it as answer( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you !!